# How to "tunnel into" objc_msgSend in Time Profiler?

Tags: objective-c, profiling, instruments, xcode-instruments

In profiling my iOS app using *Time Profiler* in *Xcode Instruments* with the *Top Functions* option selected, the `objc_msgSend` function is attributed with fully one-third of the processing cost:

[image]

Furthermore, with *Top Functions* either on or off, if I tunnel into any message sends that *Time Profiler* shows to be expensive, at each level, I see `objc_msgSend` taking up a significant portion of time at each level:

[image]

The effect as I tunnel down is a whittling away of the cost of each level by `objc_msgSend` to the point where there is little left to optimize within each of my own methods!

Now, I understand from various explanations on the web that `objc_msgSend` is extremely fast, and indeed, through my own testing of the cost of sending a message, that seems to be the case.

So, where is this cost coming from? Various posts have suggested things like "tunnel into `objc_msgSend` to see what it's calling, but as you can see from the images above, there seems to be no way to do that within *Time Profiler*.

Am I missing something fundamental here?

If `objc_msgSend` really is fast, is there a way to determine why *Time Profiler* is attributing so much of the performance cost of my app to `objc_msgSend`, and figure out what `objc_msgSend` is calling, so I can optimize my own code?

Or is it realistic that the `objc_msgSend` really is taking up one-third of the CPU in my app, and there is nothing to be done about it other than a refactoring effort to limit the number of messages sent during the execution of my app (which will move it in the direction of a less-maintainable and more fragile C-like design).

One last thing. If I select *Invert Call Tree* in an attempt to see where `obj_msgSend` is used the most, it shows methods from near the top of the call tree, which doesn't make sense, since methods farther down in the call tree must be calling `obj_msgSend` more often. Unless, of course, `obj_msgSend` is being attributed with the cost of all of the functionality it in turn calls. In which case, I'm back to the question of getting `Time Profiler` tell me where `obj_msgSend` is delegating to.

Comment: It is runtime. This is how the whole objective-c works. Each method invocation is translated into msgSend. I wonder how you skipped this part of learning objective-c.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Andy. But you didn't answer my question. I didn't ask what objc_msgSend is, and I'm not looking for an "intro-to-Objc" answer. I'm asking specifically about how to use Time Profiler to separate the performance of objc_msgSend from my app methods. The point is that objc_msgSend is too fast to be consuming one-third of the CPU, and Time Profiler seems to be smearing together the performance of objc_msgSend and the app methods. I'm looking for a way to use Time Profiler to tunnel into the objc_msgSend messages to see where in my code they call, so I can work on that.

Comment: As you noticed it is a comment, not answer. While objc_msgSend is fast, it's used in each objc expression, which makes it ubiquitous.